# Using isoweeknum with the countif function

Tags: excel, countif

I'm wondering how I could combine the isoweeknum function with an if function without a helper column.

For example I'm looking to do

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, ISOWEEKNUM(A:A)=27)
```

Which would count all columns when isoweeknum returns 27.

I've also tried

```
{=SUM(IF(ISOWEEKNUM(A:A)=27,1,0))}
```

Thanks

Comment: If that second formula, or mine does not work then your dates are text that look like dates, You have text in the column, or you have errors in the column. `ISOWEEKNUM()` will return an error if it encounters text.  check your data.

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott!

It turns out the array formula included a text header. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and limit the reference to only the data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISOWEEKNUM(A1:A100)=27))
```